# Drupal: set id attribute in multi-step form

Tags: forms, drupal

I'm building a multi-step form in Drupal 6. For some reason, the `id` attribute of the `form` element have an extra "-1" the first time the step 1 form is displayed.

For example, if the form name is "user-registration", the first time I access the step 1 form, the `id` is "user-registration-1". Then, if I go to step 2, the `id` is "user-registration". If I go back to step 1, the `id` remains "user-registration".

I'd like to know if there's a way for me to set the `id` attribute or to prevent Drupal from adding the extra "-1".

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the id yourself.

```
$form['#attributes'] = array('id' => 'user-registration');
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tested here and it added another id attribute to the form, instead of changing the value of the existing one (Drupal 6.3).

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 6.x has a form API property for both '#id' an '#attribute'.  I had the same problem and found that the '#id' property was blank, which accounted for the blank 'id' in the form field.  Then I used '#attribute' => array('id' => 'name of id'), which gave me a second 'id' in the form field.  Remove the id in the '#attribute' and add another form API property for '#id'.

```
$form['foo'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Foo'),
  '#required' => FALSE,
  '#id' => 'text-foo',    
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$form = array( '#id' => 'myformid' );
```

Comment: I doubt this will work - $form = array() clears existing $form at first.